# Get top 3 in sql

Tags: sql

```
userid bank 
------ ----
1      2009  
3      2009
3      2009
3      2009
3      2009
3      2009
2      2009  
2      2009
1      2009
1      2009
6      2009
6      2009
6      2009
6      2009
```

Here is my question i want to get the top 3 of userid I want the sql gives me this:

```
userid 3: 5 times
userid 6: 4 times
userid 1: 3 times
```

How i can get this?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Please tag your database, SQL is just a query language and have u made any effort?

Answer (score 2):

In *Standard* SQL you can do *aggregation* with `fetch first ...` method :

```
select userid, count(*)
from table t
group by userid
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 3 rows only;
```

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL you can use `fetch first` for this:

```
select userid, count(*)
from the_table
group by userid
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 3 rows only;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/KLQFS86051

Answer (score 1):

And this would be the solution in SQL Server:

```
SELECT  TOP(3) id,
        COUNT(*) Cnt
FROM    t
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

http://rextester.com/CUNDOJ55711

Answer (score 0):

The following approach is using `window` function and limit

```
select distinct userid, count(*) over(partition by userid) count_occ
from table t
order by count_occ desc
limit 3
```